# Cannot save Customer attribute data to DB in adminhtml

Tags: magento-2.1, module, database, adminhtml, customer-attribute

I need to add custom attribute for each customer. So admin can apply `Customer Type` for each customer. I've created module for this. It adds a select dropdown at the backend/adminhtml. but I cant save selected value to the database, It shows Add successful message, but When I check again, Value in select dropdown still is default value(which is an empty value). 
Here is my code, I've used two files.

**CustomerSetup.php**

```
<?php

namespace MyTheme\CustomerTypes\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\Context;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory;

class CustomerSetup extends EavSetup {

    protected $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        Context $context,
        CacheInterface $cache,
        CollectionFactory $attrGroupCollectionFactory,
        Config $eavConfig
        ) {
        $this -> eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        parent :: __construct($setup, $context, $cache, $attrGroupCollectionFactory);
    } 

    public function installAttributes($customerSetup) {
        $this -> installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup);
        $this -> installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup);
    } 

    public function installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup) {


        $customerSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'customer_pay_type',
            [
            'type' => 'int',
        'label' => 'Set Customer Type',
        'input' => 'select',
        'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'sort_order' => 200,
        'position' => 200,
        'system' => 0,
        'option' =>
        array (
            'values' =>
            array (
                0 => 'Customer Type1',
                1 => 'Customer Type2',
                2 => 'Customer Type3',
                ),
            ),

            ]
            );
        $customerSetup -> getEavConfig() -> getAttribute('customer', 'customer_pay_type')->setData('is_user_defined',1)->setData('is_required',0)->setData('default_value','')->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'adminhtml_checkout']) -> save();



    } 

    public function installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup) {

    } 

    public function getEavConfig() {
        return $this -> eavConfig;
    } 
}
```

**InstallData.php**

```
<?php

namespace MyTheme\CustomerTypes\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0') < 0){

                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $customerSetup = $objectManager->create('MyTheme\CustomerTypes\Setup\CustomerSetup');
                $customerSetup->installAttributes($customerSetup);



        }

    }
}
```

Can someone help me with this please? What is the problem here?

Comment: did you check if your field is created in customer_eav_attribute table ?

Comment: @Naveed yes, the field is created. But when I check after saving for certain, customer nothing gets saved and it shows select dropdown box with default value

Comment: @Naveed Hi, I checked again, it created my field in eav_attribute table. not in  customer_eav_attribute  . Am I missing something here? or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the code:

```
'type' => 'int',
'input' => 'select', 
'source' => 'ModuleNameSpace\YourModuleName\Model\Config\Source\Options',

 $customerSetup = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup');
```

Also create file Options.php

```
<?php

namespace ModuleNameSpace\YourModuleName\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\OptionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class Options extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{

public function getAllOptions()
{
    $this->_options=[ ['label'=>'Select Options', 'value'=>''],
                      ['label'=>'Option1', 'value'=>'1']
                      ['label'=>'Option2', 'value'=>'2']
                      ['label'=>'Option3', 'value'=>'3']
                     ];
    return $this->_options;
}

/**
 * Get a text for option value
 *
 * @param string|integer $value
 * @return string|bool
 */
public function getOptionText($value)
{
    foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
        if ($option['value'] == $value) {
            return $option['label'];
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Retrieve flat column definition
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getFlatColumns()
{
    $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
    return [
        $attributeCode => [
            'unsigned' => false,
            'default' => null,
            'extra' => null,
            'type' => Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment' => 'Custom Attribute Options  ' . $attributeCode . ' column',
        ],
    ];
}
```

}

Comment: It didnt work. Still showing default value when I re check after the save customer. could you help me?

Comment: Do you delete the old attribute in database?

Comment: yes, I delete the row in eav_attribute table,  then did setup:upgrade. after that my field is not showing at adminhtml/backend

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

> UpgradeData.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace MyTheme\CustomerTypes\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
    * put your comment there...
    * 
    * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
    * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
    */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
            /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
            $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
            /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_pay_type', [
                'type'          => 'int',
                'label'         => 'Set Customer Type',
                'input'         => 'select',
                'source'        => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
                'required'      => false,
                'user_defined'  => true,
                'sort_order'    => 110,
                'position'      => 110,
                'system'        => false,
                'option'        => ['values' => ['Customer Type1', 'Customer Type2', 'Customer Type3']],
            ]);

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_pay_type')->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' =>  ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'checkout_register']
            ]);

            $attribute->save(); 
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Updates setup_version 1.0.1 in your `module.xml` file

**After run command:**

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade